# Remote deploy (MVC and TeamCity) and encrypting Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, teamcity

Okay I'm open for suggestions with this one:

- I'm deploying an MVC site to a remote server using **TeamCity** and **MSBuild**.
- I also wish to encrypt my Web.Config upon deployment.
- I have been using **`aspnet_regiis.exe`** on the commend line to do this locally, but am not sure how to perform this on remote deploys.

The command I'm using currently is this:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/" -site "my.IIS.site.name.here"
```

Any help much appreciated... is there a TeamCity 'remote command line' tool (there is a local command line option), or should this be part of the *msproj xml* file instead?  Or is there another method entirely?

Comment: Do you have a good solution for this?

Comment: Not a direct solution, but someone suggested performing this via code in the Application_Start() method. (Maybe using c# command line call?)  Although I'm not sure how best to check if it's already been done on each App start, or if this even matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a function in my Application_Start:

```
public static void EncryptConfig(string path, string configSection)
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(path);
    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(configSection);

    if (section == null || section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) return;

    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
    config.Save();
}
```

The path variable can be filled with Request.AbsolutePath and the configSection can be "connectionStrings" for instance. Works like a charm!

Comment: I will do.  Does the `if IsProtected` ignore the section if it has already been encrypted?

Comment: Hey I'm getting the following error, possibly due to an incorrect path, but I'm unable to put in break points as it's being called in `Application_start()`.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object.

Source Error: 

 
`Line 86:       config.Save();`

Comment: What parameters are you using? try "/" and "connectionStrings"

Comment: I was trying `/Web.config` - do you not need to specify the filename too?

Comment: No, just use these. The OpenWebConfiguration opens the web.config by default. You just have to define the virtual path of where it is (hence the path variable). Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx